# Is there a way to sort by an alphanumeric column?

Tags: sql-server-2012, t-sql

I have a table **units**

| unitname |
| --- |
| unit 1 |
| unit 2b |
| unit 2c |
| unit 2a |
| unit 10 |
| unit 3a |
| unit 3c |
| unit 11 |

I want to sort the same as

| unitname |
| --- |
| unit 1 |
| unit 2a |
| unit 2b |
| unit 2c |
| unit 3a |
| unit 3c |
| unit 10 |
| unit 11 |

How can we achieve this in t-sql?

DDL

```
create table units (unitname varchar(20))
insert into units values ('unit 1'),('unit 2b'),('unit 2c'),
('unit 2a'),('unit 10'),('unit 3a'),('unit 3c'),('unit 11')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the given example values:

```
SELECT 
    U.unitname
FROM dbo.units AS U
ORDER BY
    COALESCE
    (
        TRY_CONVERT(integer, SUBSTRING(U.unitname, 6, 2)),
        TRY_CONVERT(integer, SUBSTRING(U.unitname, 6, 1))
    ),
    RIGHT(U.unitname, 1);
```

The idea is to sort by the maximum number of characters that can be successfully converted to an integer, breaking ties with the final character.

Alternatively, this idea inserts enough prefix zeros that character sorting works as expected:

```
SELECT 
    U.unitname
FROM dbo.units AS U
ORDER BY
    STUFF
    (
        U.unitname, 
        PATINDEX('%[0123456789]%', U.unitname),
        0, 
        REPLICATE
        (
            '0', 
            -- varchar(20) less the length of the existing text
            20 - DATALENGTH(U.unitname) +
            -- Plus extra zeros for trailing non-numeric characters
            PATINDEX('%[0123456789]%', REVERSE(U.unitname))
        )
    );
```

Both return:

| unitname |
| --- |
| unit 1 |
| unit 2a |
| unit 2b |
| unit 2c |
| unit 3a |
| unit 3c |
| unit 10 |
| unit 11 |

[*db<>fiddle* online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/46Fdf-fL)

---

A better table design might be:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Unit
(
    UnitNo tinyint NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT [CK dbo.Unit UnitNo positive]
            CHECK (UnitNo > 0),
    UnitSuffix char(1) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2 NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT [CK dbo.Unit Suffix blank or a-z]
            CHECK (UnitSuffix LIKE '[ a-z]'),

    CONSTRAINT [PK dbo.Unit UnitNo, UnitSuffix]
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (UnitNo, UnitSuffix)
);

INSERT dbo.Unit
    (UnitNo, UnitSuffix)
VALUES
    (1, ''),
    (2, 'b'),
    (2, 'c'),
    (2, 'a'),
    (3, 'a'),
    (3, 'c'),
    (10, ''),
    (11, '');

SELECT
    unitname = CONCAT('unit ', U.UnitNo, U.UnitSuffix)
FROM dbo.Unit AS U 
ORDER BY 
    U.UnitNo, 
    U.UnitSuffix;
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following approach

```sql
select unitname
from units
cross apply(values(stuff(unitname,1,5,''))) s(u)
cross apply(values(cast(case when isnumeric(u) = 1 
then u else left(u, len(u) - 1) end as int))) s1(num)
cross apply(values(case when isnumeric(u) = 1 
then '' else right(u,1) end)) s2(alp)
order by num,alp
```

Although this works in my case, can anyone suggest a better approach?

Answer (score -1):

I would do something like this (wrote it in pseudo-code for time purposes):

- Remove first word "unit" (optional, but makes things easier)
- Replace "1" with "1_" (using "len")
- sort non-numeric characters first (1_, 2a, 2b, 3a, etc, using "case")
- sort numeric characters second (10, 11, etc, using "else" for the previous case).